# c# I cannot get my code to sum file counts for directories beyond the root level

Tags: c#, directory

I'm using 2008 and am unable to use the `EnumerateFiles` class.

Any folder beyond the root level are essentially ignored when attempting to sum the files within listed network path. Here's my code:

```
    public void getLeverageServer(string Server)
    {
        int Inp = 0;
        int Out = 0;
        int Ex = 0;

        string output = "\\\\" + Server + "\\F\\Output";
        string input = "\\\\" + Server + "\\F\\Input";
        string exceptions = "\\\\" + Server + "\\F\\Exceptions";

        string[] pathIn = Directory.GetFiles(input);
        string[] pathOut = Directory.GetFiles(output);
        string[] pathExceptions = Directory.GetFiles(exceptions);

        foreach (string element in pathIn)
        {
            Inp++;
        }

        foreach (string element in pathOut)
        {
            Out++;
        }

        foreach (string element in pathExceptions)
        {
            Ex++;
        }

        txtLevInp.Text = Convert.ToString(Inp);
        txtLevOut.Text = Convert.ToString(Out);
        txtLevExc.Text = Convert.ToString(Ex);
        txtLevTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(Out + Ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different overload of [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string[] pathIn = Directory.GetFiles(input, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And you don't need to count the files found. Just read the value of the property `Length` of the returned array....

```
txtLevInp.Text = pathIn.Length;
```

Comment: So easy.  Thanks for cleaning up the code as well Steve!